# cudaEventElapsedTime not expected behaviour

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'm trying to compute the total time taken **in GPU** to compute something. I'm using the cudaEventRecord and cudaEventElapsedTime to determine this, but I'm having a unexpected behavior, or at least, unexpected for me :) I wrote this example to understand what's happening and I'm still confused.

In the example below I was expecting to report the same time for the three iterations but the result is:

2.80342

1003

2005.6

Which means that the total time in considering the CPU sleep time.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, is it possible do what I want?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__global__ void kernel_test(int *a, int N) {
    for(int i=threadIdx.x;i<N;i+=N) {
        if(i<N)
            a[i] = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    cudaEvent_t start[3], stop[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        cudaEventCreate(&start[i]);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop[i]);
    }

    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

    const int N = 1024 * 1024;
    int *h_a = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    int *a = 0;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&a, N * sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        cudaEventRecord(start[i], stream);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(a, h_a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);
        kernel_test<<<1, 1024, 0, stream>>>(a, N);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(h_a, a, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream);
        cudaEventRecord(stop[i], stream);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(i));

        cudaEventSynchronize(stop[i]);

        float milliseconds = 0;
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start[i], stop[i]);
        std::cout<<milliseconds<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I attach the nsight result to verify the behaviour of my example.

Windows 8.1

Geforce GTX 780 Ti

Nvidia drivers: 358.50

**EDIT:**

- Added code to be complete
- Attached nsight [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxg7uPjHnLuEYWNIX1d3UFY3MzA/view?usp=sharing)
- Added SO and drivers info
- [image: Start event], [image: end event], [image: time between]

Comment: this is not an [MCVE], please edit your question!

Comment: I agree you need to provide a complete test case.  That includes an MCVE plus your test setup (OS, compile command, GPU).  When I try and create a test on linux based on what you have shown, it seems to work correctly for me.  Example is [here](http://pastebin.com/3Baj6dtE).

Comment: You're right, I missed some code. Sorry for that. I edited the question.

Comment: Since your host allocations of `h_a` are not pinned, there will be no async behavior in your `cudaMemcpyAsync` calls. I think the WDDM explanation is quite plausible, and you haven't explained why you think it isn't. Since your GeForce GPU is in WDDM mode, any number of windows operations may be injected into the CUDA processing sequence, that the GPU must deal with. These can cause timing of operations to be modified in windows/WDDM. For example, it's entirely possible that the `cudaEventRecord(stop..` operation doesn't get flushed from the command queue until after your `sleep_for` operation

Comment: @RobertCrovella cudaMemcpyAsync is async even using non pinned memory. Pinned memory performs it faster copies but the async behaviour is the same. The WDDM explanaition makes sense but if you take a look at my nsight results the time between recorded events is 2~4 ms while the result is 3000~4000 ms. I attached a picture

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it's still async, but you've lost the ability to overlap, not that that is relevant here.  Apparently the behavior of your code is different on windows vs. linux.  That is a fairly solid indication that WDDM is getting in the way.  Furthermore, the behavior (under WDDM) can be different depending on whether the profiler is being used, and even from run to run.  The first timing measurement you have listed in your question, for example is only 3ms.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the program on Windows using the WDDM (in contrast to TCC with Tesla cards or Linux) this may be the issue:

With the WDDM kernels are not executed immediately after invocation but instead enqueued to a command buffer. Once the buffer is full it gets flushed and the enqueued commands are actually executed. Another option to force the command buffer to be explicitly flushed is to synchronize.
Now what happens is that you wait **before** the command buffer is acutally flushed...

**Edit**
Also see https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/548639/is-wddm-causing-this-/ for the problem and how `cudaEventQuery(0)` may help

Comment: That makes sense but it does not correspond to nsight results (now attached to the question)